# Trailing equals sign discarded in hyperlink on Microsoft outlook

Tags: hyperlink, outlook, character, trailing

when hyperlink is sent in an email, the hyperlink works fine as long as it doesn't end with an "=" character. e.g

```
<code>
 http://example.com/my-service?access-token=abcd1219191=
</code>
```

When seen in Microsoft Outlook on Windows the = character at the end of hyperlink is no longer a part of the hyperlink i.e

```
<code> 
<http://example.com/my-service?access-token=abcd1219191>=
</code>
```

only the part between <> remains a hyperlink , this causes link to not work as expected.

Any clues to get around this problem??

Note : The above thing works perfectly fine on Microsoft Outlook for Mac.

Comment: How exactly do you set the message body?

Comment: Can this possibly be moved to Superuser? Is is not related related to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround to solve the above problem

just replace any trailing equals sign with the encoded version i.e %3D , the hyperlink would work perfectly alright.

`e.g replace http://example.com/service/access=12snssamhsdh= with`

http://example.com/service/access=12snssamhsdh%3D

Answer (score 0):

Send Your Hyperlink with Double quotes appended at the Front and Back of the link

For Example:

send it as 
**"**http://example.com/my-service?access-token=abcd1219191=**"**

and not

http://example.com/my-service?access-token=abcd1219191=